# A different counter for each subsection subsection, but called by the same command

Tags: macros, counters, flashcards

I am writing some flashcards. The command `\flashc` is the essential one which is used to typeset the content of a flashcard. It works like this:

1. The counter is printed (on the first page of the flashcard). It gets incremented immediately after that.
2. Then the question gets printed.
3. A new page is reached by using `\newpage`. On that new, second page (or backside) of the flashcard, the reply is printed.

There are a few characteristics in regards to the content I want to consider:

- The flashcards I am writing are on specific topics in a field. I chose to follow the scripture of the main author John Smith and mirror his structure. So every topic gets put in its own section.
- Besides the main author, there are at least 2 more important authors whose work I would like to use as well. **I would like to incorporate the content of all authors (3, at the moment) in one document**.
- This yields the following structure: content by John Smith is put in the first subsection of each section, the second author (an "institute") is featured in the second subsection and an arguably young-ish author in the field gets put in the third subsection.
- However, sometimes an author has not covered a topic, so I would then call the command and the immediately continue with the next subsection, i.e. the  subsection would be empty.

## My approach

My approach so far has been to simply "clone" and rename the original definition of `\flashc`. Then I worked 3 different counters into all versions of the command/macro.

## Vision

I would just like to use `\flashc` instead of *n* versions of it.

This new command should "remember" the counter in the corresponding subsection for each author/source, so it can be continued/used in the next section, for the same *n*th subsection for the same author/source. This can be observed in the MWE.

Is this possible without defining *n* command duplicates of `\flashc`?

Or is there another elegant way to re-use the command definition with a new counter perhaps? If so, what could it look like?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
german,
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a6,
landscape,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the 1st counter - used by \flashc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{firstcount}
\setcounter{firstcount}{1}
\newcommand{\thefirstcounter}{\arabic{firstcount}\addtocounter{firstcount}{1}}

\newcommand{\flashc}[2]{%
\begin{flushleft}
\fbox{\thefirstcounter}~%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}
{#1}
\end{minipage}\end{flushleft}\newpage%
\noindent{%
#2}\newpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the 2nd counter - used by \firstcloneofflashc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{secondcount}
\setcounter{secondcount}{1}
\newcommand{\thesecondcounter}{\arabic{secondcount}\addtocounter{secondcount}{1}}

\newcommand{\firstcloneofflashc}[2]{%
\begin{flushleft}
\fbox{\thesecondcounter}~%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}
{#1}
\end{minipage}\end{flushleft}\newpage%
\noindent{%
#2}\newpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the 3rd counter - used by \secondcloneofflashc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcounter{thirdcount}
\setcounter{thirdcount}{1}
\newcommand{\thethirdcounter}{\arabic{thirdcount}\addtocounter{thirdcount}{1}}

\newcommand{\secondcloneofflashc}[2]{%
\begin{flushleft}
\fbox{\thethirdcounter}~%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}
{#1}
\end{minipage}\end{flushleft}\newpage%
\noindent{%
#2}\newpage}

\begin{document}
    
\section{The first field/topic, Walls}

\subsection{The first subsection is from a specific literature source, John Smith}

\flashc{Walls are\ldots}{not that exciting to look at.}

\subsection{Content in the second subsection(s) is always from a certain institute}

\firstcloneofflashc{Wall can be\ldots}{incredibly boring to observe. They just stand still!}

\subsection{The third subsection is for another author, namely Jane Doe}

\secondcloneofflashc{Walls are great, but\ldots}{need some proper building first.}

\secondcloneofflashc{The 2nd flashcard by Jane Doe about walls}{No idea.}

\secondcloneofflashc{Another flashcard to memorize}{How much can someone write about walls, really??}

\section{The second field/topic, Trees}

\subsection{Again the first subsection with content by John Smith}

\flashc{Yes}{No}

\subsection{The second subsection is again from content by that certain institute}

\firstcloneofflashc{Leafs}{Green}

\subsection{The third subsection for Jane Doe's comments on the matter}

\secondcloneofflashc{Trees are not}{my thing. Too woody.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @UlrichDiez I edited the op. Upon re-reading it, it wasn't really well-explained and easy to comprehend at all. Sorry for that. I hope now it is relatively ok to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that the counter A is used in any subsection ending in **x.1**, B on **x.2**, etc, you can do this:

```latex
\documentclass[
german,
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a6,
landscape,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcounter{cntA}\setcounter{cntA}{0}
\newcounter{cntB}\setcounter{cntB}{0}
\newcounter{cntC}\setcounter{cntC}{0}
\newcommand{\usecnt}{%
    \edef\letter{\Alph{subsection}}%
    \refstepcounter{cnt\letter}%
    \arabic{cnt\letter}%
}

\newcommand{\addpageauto}[2]{%
\begin{flushleft}
    \fbox{\usecnt}~
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}
    {#1}%
    \end{minipage}\end{flushleft}\newpage%
    \noindent{%
    #2}%
    \newpage
}


\begin{document}
\section{The first words}

\subsection{The first subsection with kk}
\addpageauto{stuff}{more words for that stuff}

\subsection{Another subsection with whatitis}

\addpageauto{jjjjjjjjjj}{gggggggggg}

\subsection{This is text with oijoij}

\addpageauto{22222222}{333333333}

\addpageauto{bla}{yes it was blaaaaaa}

\addpageauto{Lorem}{Ipsum}

\section{Another section to demonstrate}

\subsection{Again the first subsection with kk}

\addpageauto{Yup}{Stuff}

\subsection{This is for whatitis}

\addpageauto{kkkk}{lllll}

\subsection{And again oijoij}

\addpageauto{4444}{5555}

\end{document}
```

...clearly this will break you call it when there is no subsection or a subsection **x.4** (you have to add another counter...).

PS: using `\refstepcounter` to increase your counter will give you the possibility to `\label` and the `\ref`erence it.

Comment: Thank you. And sorry. I agree that my post was wayyy too abstract and unnecessarily obfuscated (which 100% unintentional!). I edited it, so others may understand it more easily and faster, hopefully.

Comment: The second code bit is the one I wanted. Counter A for x.1, B for x.2 and so forth.

Comment: Nice, I am happy of being of help!

Comment: I've combined your solution with the "nominative" code from my updated op. The code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/fEsZ47rE). I have encountered an unforeseen problem with it, unfortunately: if I leave the second argument of `\addpageauto` empty, LaTeX does not produce the second page (which is an unintended consequence, I hope?). I would still like to have it, for writing the solution on it by hand. Could you perhaps consider this with your code?

Comment: I have to check it, but you can try to add a `\null` before the last `\noindent`.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore?